# The (Hausdorff) moment problem for signed measures.

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

[Moment problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_problem) consider the problem of inverting the map which takes a measure $\mu$ to its moments. What type of results are known for the analogous problem with signed measures?

Namely, given $K\subset \mathbb R^d$ compact and a collection of real numbers $(M_\alpha)$ indexed by multi-indices $\alpha\in\mathbb N^d$, what conditions does one need on the $(M_\alpha)$ so as to have existence/uniqueness of a *signed* measure $\mu$ supported on $K$ such that $$\int_K x^\alpha\mu(dx)=M_\alpha?$$ Partial results/comments in this direction would also be appreciated!

The [following](http://www.digizeitschriften.de/dms/img/?PID=GDZPPN002446111) seems to address this problem, but unfortunately I don't speak a word of German and was hoping for other references!

Comment: A partial (negative) answer has been given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3246220/8157).