# A signed version of the Hausdorff moment problem

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, probability-theory

This is a follow-up to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3244628/8157) question. Let $C([0, 1])$ denote the space of real-valued continuous functions, let $\mathbb R^{\infty}$ denote the space of all real sequences, and consider the mapping of $f\in C([0, 1])$ to $(\mu_n)\in \mathbb{R}^\infty$, where 
$$\tag{1}
\mu_n(f):=\int_0^1 s^n f(s)\, ds.$$
(The letter $\mu$ stands for "moment"). As we discovered in the linked question, this mapping is not surjective, because $\mu_n(f)$ must satisfy the bound 
$$\tag{2}
|\mu_n|\le \frac{C}{n+1},$$
where $C=\sup\left\{ |f(s)|\ :\ s\in[0,1]\right\}$.

> **Question**. Suppose that $(\mu_n)\in \mathbb R^{\infty}$ is a sequence that satisfies the bound (2), for some constant $C>0$. Does there exist $f\in C([0, 1])$ such that $\mu_n=\mu_n(f)$, as in (1)?

This is similar to the [Hausdorff moment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_moment_problem), but with *signed* continuous functions, not just positive ones, in place of positive probability measures.

---

**EDIT**. The above is not the *right* question to ask, as mathworker21 clearly shows in his answer. The right question involves the mapping 
$$\tag{3}
\mu_n(m):=\int_0^1 s^n dm(s), $$
where $m$ is a signed Borel measure on $[0,1]$. This sequence needs not satisfy (2); take, for example, $m(x) =\delta(x-1)$. Instead, it satisfies $$\tag{4} \lvert \mu_n \rvert \le C, $$
where $C$ equals the total variation of $m$.

> **Refined Question**. Suppose that $(\mu_n)\in\mathbb R^\infty$ is a sequence that satisfies (4) for some constant $C>0$. Does there exist a signed Borel measure $m$ such that $\mu_n=\mu_n(m)$, as in (3)?

I have noticed that the same question has been already asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2390137/8157), without response.

My feeling is that the answer to the "Refined question" is affirmative, but that the proof is not very easy. I think that the method of proof of the Hausdorff moment problem can be adapted to the present case, but I don't know enough to do this adaptation myself.

In case I do not get any feedback, I will accept mathworker21 answer, which fully solves the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**
The two Banach spaces $l^\infty(\mathbb Z)$ and $M[0,1]$ are not isomorphic.  [reference needed]

Here,
$l^\infty(\mathbb Z)$ is the space of all bounded sequences $\big(\mu_n\big)_{n \in \mathbb Z}$ with norm $\sup\{|\mu_n| : n \in \mathbb Z\}$

$M[0,1]$ is the space of all finite signed measures on $[0,1]$ with variation norm.

Now the moment map $M[0,1] \to l^\infty(\mathbb Z)$ is linear and (by the closed graph theorem) continuous.  But since those two spaces are not isomorphic, either the moment map is not injective or it is not surjective.

Comment: Very convincing answer. I would like to remark that the continuity of the moment map does not actually require any advanced machinery. For every continuous function $\phi$, we have that $$\left\lvert \int_0^1 \phi\, dm\right\rvert \le \lVert \phi\rVert_\infty \lVert m\rVert_{\mathrm{TV}}, $$ where TV stands for "total variation". Thus, in particular, $$\left\lVert \int_0^1 s^n\, dm\right\rVert_{\ell^\infty_n}\le \lVert m\rVert_{\mathrm{TV}}, $$ which means exactly that the moment map is continuous with operator norm lesser than 1.

Comment: A follow-up [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3252808/8157).

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is "no". The point is that the map $f \mapsto (\mu_n(f))_n$ should usually be injective. Let $g(x) = 1_{[0,\frac{1}{2}]}(x)$. Then since $||g||_\infty \le 1$, we still have $\mu_n(g) \le \frac{1}{n+1}$ for each $n$. Now suppose there is some continuous function $f$ so that $\int_0^1 x^n f(x)dx = \int_0^1 x^n g(x)dx$. Then $\int_0^1 p(x)[f(x)-g(x)]dx = 0$ for any polynomial $p$, so $\int_0^1 \phi(x)[f(x)-g(x)]dx = 0$ for any $\phi \in C^\infty([0,1])$, meaning $f(x) = g(x)$ a.e.. But then $f$ can't be continuous, contradiction.

Comment: Yes, good point. Then, it is probably the case that the mapping is bijective if it is redefined as $$\mu_n(m):=\int_{[0, 1]} s^n dm(s), $$ where $m$ is a signed Borel measure on $[0, 1]$. This would be the true "signed version of the moment problem". But this is also, probably, much more difficult to prove.